# How to calculate the differential area with Jacobian?

Tags: calculus

The following are cited from [Jacobian matrix and determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#:%7E:text=The%20Jacobian%20matrix%20represents%20the,point%20where%20f%20is%20differentiable.&text=This%20means%20that%20the%20function,differential%20of%20f%20at%20x.):

> The Jacobian determinant gives the ratio of the area of the approximating parallelogram to that of the original square.

Then I made a test in Mathematica. I transformed a unit square (left figure) into a quadrilateral (right figure):

[image]

Then transformation equation is$$
\begin{cases}
x(u, v) = u(1 + v)\\
y(u, v) = v(1 + 3u)
\end{cases},
$$
and the Jacobian is $1+3u+v$. But it seems not make sense. The area of origin unit square is $1$, and the area of transformed quadrilateral is $3$.

How can I derive the area of parallelogram using Jacobian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the word *approximating* in the quote from Wikipedia; the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant $J(u,v)$ measures the area scaling when you transform an *infinitesimal* rectangle $[u,u+du] \times [v,v+dv]$ at the point $(u,v)$. In order to get the area of a finite region, you integrate (“add up” all those infinitesimal areas). If $E$ is the transformed region in the $xy$-plane, and $D$ is the unit square in the $uv$-plane, then
$$
\operatorname{Area}(E)
= \iint_E dx dy
= \iint_D \bigl| 1+3u+v \bigr| du dv
= \cdots
= 3
.
$$